# android using an image several times

Tags: android

[image][the green and red images should be in linear and must be displayed wit respective to the value in dotColors[]. ]

```
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
  dotColors = datasource.getColorsArrayForWeek(tasks.get(position).getId(), call.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));    
  LinearLayout tlli = (LinearLayout)v;
  jj=0;



jj=0; 
   while(jj<7)
   {
       if(dotColors[jj]==0)
       {
            red=(ImageView) tlli.findViewById(R.id.day1);
        }
        else if(dotColors[jj]==1)
        {
            green=(ImageView) tlli.findViewById(R.id.day2);

        }
        jj++;
        Log.i("jj::" +jj," ");
    }
    return v;
    }
```

after querying from the database the values are stored in dotColors[]. dotColors[] contains integer elements whose values are only `0 and 1..` If the value is `0` I have to display `"red"` image, if its `1` I have to display `"green"` image. how can I achieve it?
Hope the explanation is much more clear now wid the image

Comment: everytime you are initializing ImageView with day1?

Comment: Red and green have the same image reference..What are you trying to achieve, do you want to change the image of your imageview based in the jj value..?

Comment: This will happen so fast that, all you'll be able to see is the result of `jj=76`. What actually are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Is this methode is in getView() method of some base Adaptor class ?

Comment: I want to display the same image whenever the conditions are satisfied. like red green red green green

Comment: in which layout grid view or something else ?

Comment: @drawable.. yes it is in getView method in adapter..

Comment: ok I got your requirement. please add your getView method. I will change as per your requirement

Comment: @rinu0074 - just a clarification. Do you want to be able to see the `red-green-red-red-green..` changes?

Comment: What do u actually need ,you are not going to see change clearly,unless u have delay b/w setting colors

Comment: @Drawable.. I have edited in the question.. but only the while loop does the problem..

Comment: yes... wen I run, i just get the red and green alone.. but how it should look is, there must be 7 images totally, (which should be displayed as the resultnt of while loop.. ie if its 1 then green image mut be displayed, if its 0 then green

Answer (score 1):

In your Layout set both image view visibility as
     android:visibility = "GONE"
In your oncreate method

```
    red=(ImageView) tlli.findViewById(R.id.day1);
    green=(ImageView) tlli.findViewById(R.id.day2);
```

in condition

```
   if(dotColors[jj]==0)
   {
        red.setVisibility(View.Visible);
        red.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageName)
        //if ur image in folder res/drawable
    }
    else if(dotColors[jj]==1)
    {
        green.setVisibility(View.Visible);
        green.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imageName1)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> red=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourimageviewid);
>
> green=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourimageviewid);

put this in oncreate()

use setImageBitmap() to setimages dynamically

Comment: I used the following code. red.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.red) ); and I get error for "getResources()"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to be able to see the color changes. Your code executes so fast, that the changes are not visible and it directly lands up with the case where `jj=76`. Add a `Thread.sleep(millis)` in your code, to be able to see the changes.

```
jj = 0;
while (jj < 77) {
    if(dotColors[jj]==0) {
        // Do your red thingy.
    } else {
        // Do your green thingy.
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000); // every 2 secs, you can see the change. Change as per your need
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //Exception handling
    }
    Log.i("jj::" +jj," ");
    jj++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this that you want

```
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
  dotColors = datasource.getColorsArrayForWeek(tasks.get(position).getId(), call.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));    
  LinearLayout tlli = (LinearLayout)v;
  jj=0;
   while(jj<7)
   {
       if(dotColors[jj]==0)
       {
            red=(ImageView) tlli.findViewById(R.id.day1);
            red.setImageResource(R.drawable.redImage);
        }
        else if(dotColors[jj]==1)
        {
            green=(ImageView) tlli.findViewById(R.id.day1);
            green.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenImage);

        }
        jj++;
        Log.i("jj::" +jj," ");
    }
    return v;
    }
```

Comment: ohh than I must got you wrong. can you show me your layout screen shot  or some paper drawing. or paint image that this I want. happy to help you

Comment: please increase ma reputation by 2 :( so I could post the image!!

Comment: And no of image is fix ? 7

Comment: I think custom gridview is batter

Comment: is it each dot is grid cell ?

Comment: no its not.. but I started trying in gridview as well. stil in vain :(